# I would like to link the playing of a sound file to an animation execution

Tags: iphone, xcode, animation, audio

I have a little animation here of a scroll opening, then I just reverse it to have the scroll close again.  I have two questions.

- I would like to play a sound file only while the animation is
  running.  How would I do that outside of timing the start and stop
  times of the animation?  Is there some way to tie it to the animation
  execution?
- Is there a way to run the same array in reverse, rather than wasting 
  memory on having two separate arrays?

** sample code

```
- (void)loadAnimationArray;
{
    // scroll close frame order
    animationclose=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame1.png"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame2.png"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame3.png"],

                    ...

                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame25.png"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame26.png"],nil];

    // scroll open order
    animationopen=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame26.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame25.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame24.png"],

                   ...

                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame3.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame2.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame1.png"],nil];
}

- (IBAction)buttonOpen:(id)sender
{
    // default image post animation
    _imageScrollAnimation.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame1.png"];

    // setting animation parameters
    self.imageScrollAnimation.animationDuration=3;
    self.imageScrollAnimation.animationRepeatCount=1;
    self.imageScrollAnimation.animationImages=animationopen;
    [self.imageScrollAnimation startAnimating];
}

- (IBAction)buttonClose:(id)sender
{
    // default image post animation
    _imageScrollAnimation.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame26.png"];

    // setting animation parameters
    self.imageScrollAnimation.animationDuration=3;
    self.imageScrollAnimation.animationRepeatCount=1;
    self.imageScrollAnimation.animationImages=animationclose;
    [self.imageScrollAnimation startAnimating];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I ended up having to build my own crude animation player.  The idea was to have an animated scroll opening and closing upon demand with a paper rolling sound running in the background.  Essentially, I used a button to start a timer that ran through the frames of animation and started playing the sound file.  When the frame count had reached the specified level I used that to stop the timer and the sound from playing.

** ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
{
@public

@private
    BOOL scroll_open;
    int animationCount;
    NSURL *url;
    NSTimer *imageTimer;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageTextPortal;
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;

-(IBAction)buttonCloseScroll:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)buttonOpenScroll:(id)sender;
-(void)startCloseScrollAnimation;
-(void)startOpenScrollAnimation;
-(void)changeOpenScrollImage;
-(void)changeCloseScrollImage;

@end
```

** ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize imageTextPortal;

-(IBAction)buttonOpenScroll:(id)sender
{
    // starting timed open scroll sequence
    [self startOpenScrollAnimation];
}

-(IBAction)buttonCloseScroll:(id)sender
{
    // starting timed close scroll sequence
    [self startCloseScrollAnimation];
}

-(void)startOpenScrollAnimation
{
    // playing the sound
    NSError *error;
    url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"rolling" ofType:@"mp3"]];
    _audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    _audioPlayer.delegate = self;
    _audioPlayer.volume = 1.0;
    [_audioPlayer play];

    // setting animation count for decrement
    animationCount = 26;

    // starting timer
    imageTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.035 target:self selector:@selector(changeOpenScrollImage) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)changeOpenScrollImage
{
    // switching image
    self.imageTextPortal.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"frame%i.png" , animationCount]];

    // decrementing image count
    --animationCount;

    // testing for end of animation
    if (animationCount < 1)
    {
        // turning off timer
        [imageTimer invalidate];
        imageTimer = nil;

        // stopping sound play
        [_audioPlayer stop];

        // setting default image after the animation
        imageTextPortal.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame1.png"];
    }
}

-(void)startCloseScrollAnimation
{
    // playing the sound
    NSError *error;
    url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"rolling" ofType:@"mp3"]];
    _audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    _audioPlayer.delegate = self;
    _audioPlayer.volume = 1.0;
    [_audioPlayer play];

    // setting animation count for decrement
    animationCount = 1;

    // starting timer
    imageTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.035 target:self selector:@selector(changeCloseScrollImage) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)changeCloseScrollImage
{
    // switching image
    self.imageTextPortal.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"frame%i.png" , animationCount]];

    // incrementing image count
    ++animationCount;

    // testing for end of animation
    if (animationCount > 26)
    {
        // turning off timer
        [imageTimer invalidate];
        imageTimer = nil;

        // stopping sound
        [_audioPlayer stop];

        // setting default image after the animation
        imageTextPortal.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame26.png"];
    }
}

@end
```